# Is there a comprehensive list of indigenous Australian taxa?

Tags: data-request, environment, australia

I'm fitting models of species' distributions and community composition using occurrence data provided by the [Atlas of Living Australia](http://www.ala.org.au/) (a node of [GBIF](http://www.gbif.org/)).

Is there a comprehensive list of names of indigenous Australian taxa (either flora, fauna or both), or a global list of taxa that indicates countries in the native range? Alternatively, is there a web API that I can query for these data?

Ideally I'd be able to easily relate returned taxon names to [LSIDs](http://www.ipni.org/lsids.html) such that I can associate them with the ALA occurrence data.